# Get id value and set as link rel with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gallery

I'm using [Lightview](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview/documentation/usage) with WordPress, and trying to give WP galleries the necessary rels and classes. The default gallery markup is something like:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-1">
    <dl class="gallery-item">
       <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <a href="image-link"><img src="xxx" /></a>
       </dt>
    </dl>
    <dl class="gallery-item">
       <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <a href="image-link"><img src="xxx" /></a>
       </dt>
   </dl>
</div>
```

Using jQuery i need to put a class on links (to trigger Lightview) and an attribute (to group them when viewing). I could get the simple part:

```
$(".gallery-icon a").attr('class','lightview');
$(".gallery-icon a").attr('data-lightview-group','group');
```

It works. The class="lightview" activates, and the data-lightview-group attribute keeps all images in a single group "group" for best navigation. This way, the original code turns like this:

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-1">
    <dl class="gallery-item">
       <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <a href="image-link" class="lightview" data-lightview-group="group"><img src="xxx" /></a>
       </dt>
    </dl>
    <dl class="gallery-item">
       <dt class="gallery-icon">
       <a href="image-link" class="lightview" data-lightview-group="group"><img src="xxx" /></a>
       </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

But if there is a long page with more than one gallery, they are merged, because all links will have the same "data-lightview-group".

There is a way to get the id from each gallery and use them as value to this data-lightview-group attribute? Or any other approach to have a unique value in all links for each gallery?

Comment: I haven't worked with WP in a while, but shouldn't you just be able to edit the theme and have it produce the correct HTML?

Comment: If i do this way so i should word with some filter, because the part that render galleries are in core files of WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to assign different group names to each gallery:

```
// for each gallery
$('.gallery').each(function() {

    // add lightview class
    $(this).find(".gallery-icon a").attr('class','lightview');

    // set a unique group name (group-<id of this galley>)
    $(this).find(".gallery-icon a").attr('data-lightview-group', 'group-' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **.each** like

```
$(".gallery-icon a").each(function(){
     $(this).attr('data-lightview-group','group');
     $(this).attr('class','lightview');
     //Better to use addClass like
     -->$(this).addClass('lightview');
});
```

and if you want to merge the id to the data-lightview-group add this

```
var this_group = 'group'+$(this).attr('id');
$(this).attr('data-lightview-group',this_group);
```

Comment: `$('.gallery').each(function() {
    $(this).find(".gallery-icon a").attr('class','lightview');
    $(this).find(".gallery-icon a").attr('data-lightview-group', 'group-' + $(this).attr('id'));
});`

This works perfectly, far best way than i was trying. Thanks!

Comment: both yours and mines and techfoobar are same approx